# Floating text around a non-rectangular object

Tags: html, css, css-float

I need to float some text around a spangle on my page as you can see on the attached screenshot. I'd like to not to use JavaScript. Is that possible to do in pure CSS?

[image: example of the layout]

Comment: CSS3 has some features for [animating](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp), but older browsers won't be able to perform it then. Check the availability up [here](http://caniuse.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS shapes if you're not too worried about compatability with older browsers.

```
.element{
  shape-outside: url(image.png);
  shape-image-threshold: 0.5;
  float: left;
}
```

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/

Comment: This is the only css solution that exists today. +1

Comment: That is a good solution, but it lacks on browser compatibility. It is not even supported by the latest Firefox or Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Might the `padding` attribute be what you mean?

```css
.container {
  background: url('someimage.png') no-repeat left bottom;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  color: #666;
  font: 9pt/14pt 'consolas';
  padding: 40px 12px 12px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Oooh... I didn't know that you meant the text bending over the image! sorry, See evilunix' answer, as I don't want to copy someone else's solution.